# Reading CSV file which has xml content and trying to write only the content i needed. I'm using StringTokenizer

Tags: java, arrays, string, csv, stringtokenizer

In Excel file Row A has 8000 columns which has xml in each column as shown below.So i need read the entire file and write only phoneNumber which is inside the each column.

```
OutputElements: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ns2:xxxxxxxx xmlns:ns2="http://webservice.com/"><ns2:xxxxxxx><ns2:xxxxxx>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?&gt;&lt;xxxxxxxx;&lt;xxxxxxxxxx keyword="TEXT" phoneNumber="+123456789" pinNumber=123456 /&gt;&lt;/xxxxxxxxxxx&gt;&lt;;</ns2:xxxxxxxxx><ns2:messageType>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</ns2:messageType><ns2:xxxxxxx>3456</ns2:xxxxxxx><ns2:id>xxxxxxx</ns2:id></ns2:xxxxxxxx></ns2:xxxxxxxxx>
```

My Code:

```
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line = null;
    String isPhoneNumber ="phoneNumber=";

        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(isPhoneNumber);
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,"");
        while(st.hasMoreElements() || matcher.equals(isPhoneNumber)){
            System.out.println("OutputElements: " +st.nextElement());
                }


        }
        reader.close();
```

I'm reading the file. And i need to write only the phoneNumber='123456789' as output. SubString is in my mind and also i need to use REGEX, Matchers and Patterns. Can someonehelp me?

Comment: if it is a xml then why don't you use parsers, is it heavier than this.

Comment: In Excel file Row A has 8000 columns which has xml in each column.So i need read the entire file and write only phoneNumber.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't missing all that much from your code other than the regex. I recommend just using a pattern and matcher to retrieve the data rather than a substring, heres a working sample for you:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 *
 * @author dean2191
 */
public class JavaApplication6 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file));
            String line = null;
            String isPhoneNumber ="phoneNumber=\"\\+?[0-9]+\"";

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(isPhoneNumber);
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,"");
                int count=0;
                while(matcher.find()){
                          count++;
                     System.out.println("Match number "
                              + count);
           System.out.println(matcher.group());

                }


            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication6.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

I made the '+' optional so you could theoretically deal with it being missing, anyway hope this helps if you have any questions id be happy to help.